# How to formulate a TSQL CTE expression for total counts?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a table with raw data that I want to return distinct people_id counts from. How can I do this in a CTE if the counts have different groupings? Here is what I have so far:

```
;with cte as 
    (select 
       program_modifier_id, program_modifier, people_id, group_profile_id, 
       current_status, license_number, is_managing_office,
       program_info, program_name, program_code, group_profile_type_id
     From
    #enrollments en with (nolock) )
 SELECT 'TN - Level 4', 
     CASE WHEN (program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' )
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT people_id) END AS 'Total Ct' 
 from cte 
 group by program_modifier_id
    UNION

 SELECT 'TN - Level 3 CE - RTC', 
     CASE WHEN (program_modifier_id = '213D080F-E340-44B6-AC8C-4233D1193602' 
                      AND license_number like '%-RTC-%')
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT people_id) END AS 'Total Ct' 
 from cte 
 group by program_modifier_id, license_number
```

The output from this is:

```
TN - Level 3 CE - RTC   49
TN - Level 3 CE - RTC   38
TN - Level 4    56
TN - Level 3 CE - RTC   7
TN - Level 3 CE - RTC   24
TN - Level 3 CE - RTC   NULL
TN - Level 4    NULL
```

But I want output to look like:

```
TN - Level 3 CE - RTC   118
TN - Level 4    56
```

So the problem is two-fold.  First, some of these counts include more than one condition in the WHERE clause.  For example, program_modifier_id vs. program_modifier_id and license_number.  The second problem is that using the TSQL code above, I have to group by both program_modifier_id AND license_number in order to include license_number in the WHERE clause.  But I don't want a breakdown for that count on license_Number.  I just want the total count, regardless of license_number.  How can I modify this TSQL query to achieve desired counts?

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as 
    (select 
       program_modifier_id, program_modifier, people_id, group_profile_id, 
       current_status, license_number, is_managing_office,
       program_info, program_name, program_code, group_profile_type_id
     From
    #enrollments en with (nolock) )

 Select Description,SUM([Total Ct]) as [Total Ct] from
 (   
 SELECT 'TN - Level 4' as Description, 
     CASE WHEN (program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' )
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT people_id) END AS 'Total Ct' 
 from cte 
 group by program_modifier_id
 ) a Group by Description

 UNION

 Select Description,SUM([Total Ct]) from
 (  
 SELECT 'TN - Level 3 CE - RTC'as Description, 
     CASE WHEN (program_modifier_id = '213D080F-E340-44B6-AC8C-4233D1193602' 
                      AND license_number like '%-RTC-%')
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT people_id) END AS 'Total Ct' 
 from cte 
 group by program_modifier_id, license_number 
 ) a Group by Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  It turned out to be super simple!  This was my solution:

```
;with cte as (
select 
*
From
    #enrollments en with (nolock)
)

SELECT 'TN - Level 4 TOTAL', count(distinct people_id) from #enrollments where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' AND group_profile_id in ('3EC657F7-655F-43FB-8424-2A8914E7C725','9D1628F0-CF85-464C-815A-8660AF60978F','D7C59915-067A-4A03-8B8C-23783568C8D3') AND (@Status is NULL OR current_status = @Status)
UNION
SELECT 'TN - Level 4 IH', count(distinct people_id) from #enrollments where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' AND group_profile_id = 'D7C59915-067A-4A03-8B8C-23783568C8D3' AND (@Status is NULL OR current_status = @Status)
UNION
SELECT 'TN - Level 4 CIRT', count(distinct people_id) from #enrollments where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' AND group_profile_id = '3EC657F7-655F-43FB-8424-2A8914E7C725' AND (@Status is NULL OR current_status = @Status)
```